# Returning parameters of YUI DataTable from function

Tags: javascript, json, yui-datatable, yui2

This is in reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293738/yui-datatable-custom-column-definitions-and-data) question.

I have to use the script mentioned in the approved answer at various pages. So, I have kept the part till the line
`this.ds.dataProvider = this;` in an external JS file.

Now, since I am to reuse the prototyping, how do I get reference to the DataTable's constructor arguments in the page which references this JS, i.e. `"basic", columnList, this.ds` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't know this question was posted under a different context so posting solution to close thread.

Used this solution : [How to use YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest and return results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159368/how-to-use-yahoo-util-connect-asyncrequest-and-return-results)